# How to make this Python program compile?

Tags: python, syntax-error

I have this Python code:

```
import re
s = "aa67bc54c9"
for t, n in re.findall(r"([a-z]+)([0-9]+)", s)
```

And I get this error message when I try to run it:

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    for t, n in re.findall(r"([a-z]+)([0-9]+)", s)
                                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How can I solve this? I am new to Python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a colon (`:`) on the end of the line.

And after that line, you will need an indented statement(s) of what to actually *do* in the loop.  If you don't want to do anything in the loop (perhaps until you get more code written) you can use the statement `pass` to indicate basically a no-op.

In Python, you need a colon at the end of

- for statements
- while statements
- if/elif/else statements
- try/except statements
- class statements
- def (function) statements

Comment: Don't forget Class and def statements.

Answer (score 7):

`for` starts a loop, so you need to end the line with a `:`, and put the loop body, indented, on the following lines.

EDIT:

For further information I suggest you go to the [main documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement).

Comment: An improvement to this answer might include "read about the for statement syntax in the Python language reference": http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement